# setting up application configuration during runtime

Tags: libgdx

Can we directly make changes for ApplicationConfigurations, while game is running? For example, I have SettingsScreen, and when I press some button for changing to full screen, it will take effect instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
To change to fullscreen og change window size while game is running:

```
     Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(int width, int height, boolean fullscreen)
```

[EDIT]
sry, I remembered this from an old version.

It is now:

```
Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(int x, int y)
```

and

```
Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode())
```

Comment: IntelijIdea says: cannot resolve method. What libgdx version is that? I have latest.

Comment: try Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(int x, int y) and setFullscreenMode(boolean fullscreen) instead.

Comment: `Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(int x, int y)` this is cool and works. However, to setFullScreenMode, it does not take boolean, it takes instance of DisplayMode, and parameters width/height, instead of setting it to full screen like true/false ? Any other idea ?

Comment: Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode()); maybe? I'm at work now so can't really test it.

Comment: That was easy, I totaly forgot about getter for DisplayMode instance. Thank you very much!